# rake aborted while creating admin user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu, rubygems

I am using ubuntu 18.4, Ruby 2.7.3 , rails 4.2.11.1, Rake 10.0.0

While trying to run the `rake admin:create`, I am getting the below error message. Can any one help me on this.

```
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/version.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant URI::VERSION_CODE
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/uri-0.10.1/lib/uri/version.rb:3: warning: previous definition of VERSION_CODE was here
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/version.rb:4: warning: already initialized constant URI::VERSION
```

Comment: Those are "just" warnings. `rake` should not quit when there is a warning. Can you please post the whole output of the `rake` command?

Comment: Hi , i resolved the issue from my end. Since the uri two versions in my program it throws error. The above reported issue resolved after removed the uri latest one.

Comment: Very interesting combination.  Rails 4.2 is well past EOL.  Recommended ruby version for 4.2 is only 2.2, I am kinda surprised you are able to get it to run at all.. Good luck to you!

Comment: Actually i am trying to install the IPaaS platform in ubuntu as per the instruction given in cenit-io.github.io/docs/# –